# Extracting values from string using regex failing

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm basically trying to gather data from an API using regex however my code is returning a `null` value?

The regex string I'm using is this:

```
let matches;

await emails.data.forEach(obj => {
    console.log(obj.mail_text_only); // <div>Be sure to <a href="https://www.website.com/unlock/verifyemail.html?requestId=%2F5xHTj30QFhcXmoyOHSlXA%3D%3D&validationId=bk72uGeIEk6KWOGNE8xF%2Fs4roEANsL0Y5pgVorJIjAI%3D&bitmap=POSTPAID">confirm</a> your unlock request within 24 hours or it'll be canceled.</div>
    matches = obj.mail_text_only.match(/requestId=(.*)&validationId=(.*)&bitmap=(.*)"/g);
});

console.log(matches); //null
```

And my string is formatted as such:

```
<div>Be sure to <a href="https://www.website.com/unlock/verifyemail.html?requestId=%2F5xHTj30QFhcXmoyOHSlXA%3D%3D&validationId=bk72uGeIEk6KWOGNE8xF%2Fs4roEANsL0Y5pgVorJIjAI%3D&bitmap=POSTPAID">confirm</a> your unlock request within 24 hours or it'll be canceled.</div>
```

When I run `console.log(matches)` it's throwing a `null` result?

Comment: Try using https://regex101.com/

Comment: Works here: https://regex101.com/r/taqJD4/1

Comment: @user120242 If it's not matching anything with greedy matcher, it won't match with lazy either.

Comment: take away the single quotes.  you're using a string not a regex literal

Comment: On an unrelated note, the `await` you've got there doesn't do anything useful; you can remove that.

Comment: @Jacob agh thankyou, I have a feeling this is something related to the fact I've got it wrapped in a callback function so it's not updating my `matches` value?

Comment: I think it's that `"` at the end; at least in what you posted, the string your matching doesn't have a `"` at the end, so it won't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. Regex has not quotes.

```js
let str = "https://www.website.com/unlock/verifyemail.html?requestId=%2F5xHTj30QFhcXmoyOHSlXA%3D%3D&validationId=bk72uGeIEk6KWOGNE8xF%2Fs4roEANsL0Y5pgVorJIjAI%3D&bitmap=POSTPAID"

let matches = str.match(/requestId=(.*)&validationId=(.*)&bitmap=(.*)/g);


console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp you should not include quotes around your regex. When I test this with a console it works without the single quotes:

```
>> matches = a_string.match(/requestId=(.*)&validationId=(.*)&bitmap=(.*)/g);
>> Array [ "requestId=%2F5xHTj30QFhcXmoyOHSlXA%3D%3D&validationId=bk72uGeIEk6KWOGNE8xF%2Fs4roEANsL0Y5pgVorJIjAI%3D&bitmap=POSTPAID\">confirm</a> your unlock request within 24 hours or it'll be canceled.</div>" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this one:

```
match(/requestId=[\w!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+&validationId=[\w!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+&bitmap=[\w!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+/g)
```

- `\w`   will match all numbers & characters (equivalent to 0-9, a-z, A-Z)
- `!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-`   will match all special characters